# JNI Memory model

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I want to understand how the different memory segments are set up when an android or java app uses native code using JNI.

Native code is packaged as a shared lib inside the APK.
When the shared lib is requested to load using `System.loadLibrary` call, Is the shared lib loaded into the JVM or into a different process executing natively as a normal C/C++ application? More importantly does the shared lib start using heap, stack and other memory segments of JVM? Does the code from the shared lib execute under the context of JVM?

I visualize it like: Java code consists of bytecode, so JVM interprets it. But when Java makes a native call, the native code of the shared lib is executed directly by the JVM without any interpretation. Please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: JVM is written in C++ So when Java makes a native call it actually means that JVM runtime makes a regular C call. Your native code can interact with JVM state only through jni.

Comment: (1) it's loaded into your process. (2) it does not use memory from the JVM; unless you make JNI calls to create Java objects etc. (3) by default JNI calls are attached to a JVM thread. (4) C and C++ compile to machine code so no interpretation is possible.  You should read the JNI spec https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html